# How do I view frequency of disk I/O wait states in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, performance, command

I can see most everything except this statistic between the Task Manager, Performance Monitor, and Resource Monitor.  On linux, this is fairly easy to get at via the `iostat` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfmon -> Click on the + to add a counter.

Select LogicalDisk from the drop down.

Add: Avg Disk Queue Length and/or Current Disk Queue Length. There are also separate counters for read/write queue lengths and you can isolate by different drive letters, too.